# Не открывается приложение в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Помогите пожалуйста! Работал в Visual Studio над проектом на С#, всё было хорошо, но после написания цикла while в publick Form, проект перестал открываться. Его видно только через диспетчер задач, Visual Studio тоже показывает что приложение открыто, но его нет.

Comment: В конструкторе формы написали бесконечный цикл? Ну, придётся убрать его. Пока конструктор не отработает, форма не отрисуется.

Comment: Покажите ваш цикл и где он используется

Comment: Покажите код вашей формы, для начала. Здесь есть такое правило оформелния вопроса: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._ - А так, ответ прост: уберите цикл `while`, который вы написали, и все заработает. Не можете убрать? Он вам нужен? Зачем? Чем подробнее расскажете, тем точнее будет ответ.